# C# Beginner, writing/calling a Method

Tags: c#, .net, methods

When we write a method, say an easy one like

```
  void myMethod()
    {
    // code here
    // 
    }
```

and we call it from within Main(), it's done essentially this way:

```
Program myProgram = new Program ();
myProgram.myMethod();
```

Obviously, `myProgram` is entirely arbitrary (taking into consideration, of course, coding conventions) but what's up with the reference to `Program`?

Comment: That's the name of the type where the instance method `myMethod` is declared.

Comment: I would recommend you read a good [introductory C# book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-c0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your method `myMethod` inside a class called `Program`.  Since your method is not a `static` method (i.e. it is not `static void myMethod()`) it requires an instance of `Program` in order to work.  Therefore you need to create a new instance of `Program` in order to invoke `myProgram.myMethod()` on it.  If `myMethod` *were* static, you could have called it simply by `Program.myMethod()` or, since you're already inside that class to begin with, `myMethod()` (since the current class name is implied for static methods).

Comment: I went back to my code; I added static in front of myMethod, and in doing so the Program myMethod = new Program() became unnecessary (uncompilable? illegal?), and it can be called simply by writing myMethod()

Answer (score 1):

Program is a class, which contains methods.  By default the only method it contains is `static void Main(...)`.

If you add your non-static method `myMethod` it doesn't belong to the **class** Program, but rather to **instances** of Program (called objects).

Static methods (like Main) can be called directly from the class:

```
Program.Main(...);
```

Non-static methods must be called from objects of the class:

```
Program program = new Program();
program.myMethod();
```

Classes are designed to group together like functionality.  Program isn't a good place to put these.  You should create other classes, and use them throughout your code.

By using classes you keep like code together, and provide a mechanism to reuse the same code over again from different places.  You can create as many different instances of 'Program' as you like, from many different classes, and invoke the 'myMethod' method on each of them.

For instance you might have a `ClassRoster` and a `Student` class, which can be used like this in the `ClassScheduler` class:

```
ClassRoster roster = new ClassRoster();

Student studentOne = new Student();
studentOne.StudentId = "123456";

roster.EnrollStudent(studentOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Program` is the type, that defines `myMethod` in your question. In C# methods are defined by types.

You can either call methods via an instance of the defining type or via the type itself (if the method is static). Since `myMethod` isn't static, you need an instance of the type `Program` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 public void myMethod()
    {
    // code here

    }
```

in main method:

```
Program myProgram = new Program();
myProgram.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
I went back to my code; I added `static` in front of myMethod, and in doing so the Program myMethod = new Program() became unnecessary (uncompilable? illegal?), and it can be called simply by writing `myMethod()` Obviously I need to study up on what static does and how it affects methods/classes!

I'm actually only in week #3 of my .NET class... our instructor, while very smart, leaves something to be desired in the teacher category. The assigned text for the class is only so-so in my opinion, at least for me and how I learn (*Programming C#*, O'Reilly) This is a very good community, thanks!